# nvidia ppa not recognized

Tags: 16.04, uefi, ppa, add-apt-repository, nvidia-geforce

I have just done a clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install on my MSI GS40 Phantom 6QE, ive got the dual harddrives connected and all of the graphics look fine while using the stock Xorg drivers and i dont have any problems anywhere, but I might want to do some gaming later and I have got a GTX 970M graphics card so why not get it running right?

I had a problem running in legacy mode with the nvidia-641 drivers giving me the login loop so I re-installed in UEFI to hard set my secure boot to disabled.

Now I am both, curious to see if the drivers cause the same problem in UEFI with sec boot off, and prepared to fix the problem again if i get the login loop again.

Here's the problem, when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

I can pull down the nvidia drivers but i cant get access to nvidia-364, which everyone says is the fix to the login loop issue.

When I run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

I get an error stating that the PPA is unknown.
I am seeing that if I add this PPA I can fix the loop error with the newer drivers, so does anyone know about this ppa error?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` yet? That PPA looks correct, and works on my 16.04 machine.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense.

Comment: @ubashu it makes sense to me.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yea i have

Comment: @Tucker Don't write your answer in the question itself; please post the answer separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the proprietary intel driver and then running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get-upgrade
```

after enableing the intel driver, i was able to add the repository, but the nvidia-364 driver still threw an error though when i tried to install using

```
apt-get install
```

so i ran apt-get update / upgrade again and was able to install nvidia-364.

logged out and was able to log in, loop resolved

update:
double checked that nvidia-364 binary driver was installed and running, full shut down, still no login loop

Comment: I'll delete my answer. You deserve the reputation.

Comment: command `sudo apt-get-upgrade` not found

Comment: probably he meant `sudo apt-get upgrade`